# How do I embed a video in a MS Access 2010 form?

Tags: ms-access

I need to be able to play a video in a form. The user should be able to add video's and play back the added video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access has a built-in [Windows Media Player active-x control](http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/showflat.php?Cat=&Board=83&Number=739249&Zf=&Zw=wmp&Zg=0&Zl=d&Main=738060&Search=true&where=&Zu=&Zd=l&Zn=&Zt=3d&Zs=a&Zy=#Post739249&Zp=).

Comment: Er, Access has no such control, but you can use the Windows-provided ActiveX control from within Access. That list of controls that you get in the form designer with the button down at the bottom is specifically the non-Access ActiveX controls installed on the system. They may or may not work well in Access.